# let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. Show that $\det(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det(A)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix , and then show that $$\det(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det(A)}.$$

Any tips on this one? basically I don't have a clue.

Comment: If you have proved that for square matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same size, we have $\text{det}(AB)=\text{det}(A)\text{det}(B)$, it will be easy. If you have to *prove* the above multiplication law, not easy.

Comment: I guess I can just assume that det(AB) = det(A)det(B)(aka dont have to prove it) :) but im not sure how this helps me?

Comment: $A\cdot A^{-1} = I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: We know that $AA^{-1} = I$.  We also have the fact that, in general $det(AB) = det(A)det(B)$.  Can you see where to go from here?

Comment: nope, not really and idk what you mean with AA^-1 = I? just matrix A * inverse matrix A = I ? :/

Comment: @yyzzer1234, Try to combine the two facts that Kaj_H wrote down. In other words, try to calculate $\det(AA^{-1})$

Comment: Yep, you're on the right track.

Comment: its just 1 isnt it?

Comment: Certainly.  Now bring home the proof:  Why is $det(A) = 1/det(A^{-1})$?

Comment: Another hint: You now know that $\det(I)=1$, and that $AA^{-1}=I$, therefore $\det(AA^{-1})=1$. Now, try to calculate $\det(AA^{-1})$ another way.

Answer (score 1):

From properties of the determinant, for square matrices $A$ and $B$ of equal size we have
$$
|AB|=|A||B|,
$$
which means determinants are distributive. This means that the determinant of a matrix inverse can be found as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
|I|&=\left|AA^{-1}\right|\\
1&=|A|\left|A^{-1}\right|\\
\left|A^{-1}\right|&=\frac{1}{|A|},
\end{align}
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is not [defective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix),  there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $D=P^{−1}AP$ that diagonalizes $A$.

The diagonal entries of $D^{-1}$ are the reciprocals of the entries of $D$ and since the determinante of a diagonal matrix is the product of all diagonal entries it follows that:
$$
\det(A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det(A)}.
$$